# Memory and Runtime Issues: Ukkonens Algorithm for SuffixTrees in python

Tags: python, memory, runtime, suffix-tree

I have troubles concerning both runtime and memory usage, when using python to compute a suffix tree via Ukkonens Algorithm (linear time and space).

Currently, I want to create a suffix tree for a bacterial genome, consisting of roughly 1,6 Million characters in length. The alphabet contains of 11 different characters. The file itself has a size of 1,6 MB, but the tree in Python uses more than 2 GB RAM and it takes about one minute to finish building the tree.
I am storing child nodes in a list of length 11, where each positions corresponds to a character of the alphabet. I have tried using dictionaries, as a lot of None values are stored by using this method. However, this results in even larger memory issues and takes a little bit longer.
I am not even storing the sequence itself but only the corresponding intervals.
I am no expert, is this overhead, produced by all of the objects?
Can this be reduced?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Below is the contructor of a SuffixNode in the tree.
As you can see, children are stored in a list.
The edge, that connects to the parent node is only stored with _start and _end.

```
class SuffixNode:

_index = -1

def __init__(self, start, end,suffixlink = None):
    self._start = start
    self._end = end
    self._index = -1
    self._suffixlink = None
    self._children = [None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None]
```

The algorithm itself, although this might not be quite helpful:
class SuffixTree(object):

```
def __init__(self,sequence):
    self.end = len(sequence)+1
    self.sequence = sequence+'#'
    self.virt_root = SuffixNode(-1,-1)
    self.root = SuffixNode(0, 0)
    self.virt_root.setChild(self.root,self.getChildPosition('A'))
    self.virt_root.setChild(self.root,self.getChildPosition('C'))
    self.virt_root.setChild(self.root,self.getChildPosition('G'))
    self.virt_root.setChild(self.root,self.getChildPosition('T'))
    self.virt_root.setChild(self.root,self.getChildPosition('#'))
    self.virt_root.setChild(self.root,self.getChildPosition('M'))
    self.virt_root.setChild(self.root,self.getChildPosition('K'))
    self.virt_root.setChild(self.root, self.getChildPosition('N'))
    self.virt_root.setChild(self.root,self.getChildPosition('W'))
    self.virt_root.setChild(self.root, self.getChildPosition('S'))
    self.virt_root.setChild(self.root, self.getChildPosition('R'))
    self.virt_root.setChild(self.root, self.getChildPosition('Y'))
    self.root.setSuffixLink(self.virt_root)
    self.virt_root.setChild(self.root,self.getChildPosition('#'))
    current_char = sequence[0]
    self.root.setChild(SuffixNode(1,self.end,self.root),self.getChildPosition(current_char))
    s = self.root
    k = 2
    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=len(self.sequence))
    bar.start()
    for i in range(2,len(self.sequence)+1):
        bar.update(i)
        s, k = self._update(s, k, i-1, i)

    bar.finish()
    self.index(self.root, self.end)

def getChildPosition(self,char):

    intToReturn = -1
    if char == 'A':
        return 0
    if char == 'C':
        return 1
    if char == 'G':
        return 2
    if char == 'T':
        return 3
    if char == 'M':
        return 4
    if char == 'N':
        return 5
    if char == 'S':
        return 6
    if char == 'Y':
        return 7
    if char == 'K':
        return 8
    if char == 'R':
        return 9
    if char == 'W':
        return 10
    if char == '#':
        return 11


def _update(self, s, k, p, pos):


    current_char = self.sequence[pos-1]
    old_r = self.root
    s, k = self._canonize(s, k, p)
    done, r = self._testAndSplit(s, k, p, current_char)
    while done is False:
        r.setChild(SuffixNode(pos, self.end, self.root), self.getChildPosition(current_char))
        if old_r != self.root:
            old_r.setSuffixLink(r)
        old_r = r
        s, k = self._canonize(s.getSuffixLink(), k, p)
        done, r = self._testAndSplit(s, k, p, current_char)
    if old_r != self.root:
        old_r.setSuffixLink(s)

    return s, k

def _canonize(self, s, k, p):
    length = p-k+1
    while length > 0:
        key = self.sequence[k-1]
        child = s.getChild(self.getChildPosition(key))
        edgeLength = child.getEdgeLength()
        if edgeLength > length or child.isLeaf():
            break
        k = k+edgeLength
        length = p-k+1
        s = child
    return s, k

def _testAndSplit(self, s, k, p, current_char):

    length = p-k+1

    if length == 0:
        child = s.getChild(self.getChildPosition(current_char))
        if child is None:

            return False, s
        else:

            return True, s
    else:
        old_char = self.sequence[k - 1]
        child = s.getChild(self.getChildPosition(old_char))
        start = child.getStart()
        if current_char == self.sequence[start+length-1]:

            return True, s
        else:

            newChild = SuffixNode(child.getStart(), child.getStart()+length-1,self.root)
            newChild.setChild(child, self.getChildPosition(self.sequence[child.getStart()+length-1]))
            child.setStart(child.getStart()+length)
            s.setChild(newChild, self.getChildPosition(old_char))

            return False, newChild


def index(self, node, offset):

    for child in node.getChildren():
        if child is not None:
            if  child.isLeaf():
                child.setIndex(offset-child.getEdgeLength())
            else:
                child.setIndex(self.index(child,offset-child.getEdgeLength()))
```

update : updates the tree when inserting next character

canonize : walks towards leaves as far as possible to get the nearest node, where a branchpoint could be.

testandSplit: test, if an edge must be split and generates a new node if yes.

index: generates index for leaves of tree

Comment: Yeah, Python data types can be rather [wasteful](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/python-memory-management.html). Also, double check that you are not copying things by value if you don't need copies. But without seeing your code and some memory profiling, it's hard to tell if this can be improved.

Comment: Can you give me a short explanation on not copying things by value? The problem is (as far as I know, that python uses "by assignment" operations) Whenever an object is not used any more, it should be thrown away right?

Comment: What operations will you need to perform on your suffix tree afterwards ? Because it might be wiser to actually use an existing implementation of ukkkonen's tree, rather than reinventing the wheel (no offense, it's a very common things among programmers). So I'd advice trying to use some existing implemetation available on some git repository.